# WindowsForms DataGridView speed like in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ssms

Does anyone know how Microsoft made their DataGridView in SQL Server Management Studio work so fast? I'm implementing a Windows Forms application and I did bind my BindingSource with object. Later I load data via Entity Framework and set loaded collection as DataSource.

But that not the point. When I have ~25 000 rows, the scrolling appears to be slow, like in a low frame rate. When I load same data from SQL Server Management Studio scrolling is not a problem. It renders fast and smooth.

Did anyone achieve the same performance?

Comment: Did you find the an answer meanwhile? (To the question: Does anyone know how Microsoft made their DataGridView in SQL Server Management Studio?)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624.aspx

Using Virtual Mode you can specify the amount of data during the scroll. I haven't used it but I was looking into Grid's editing.

I hope this helps.